# Awk exact string match in a specific column only returns header row

Tags: windows-10, csv, awk

I have a 6-7M row CSV file that end users wish to review with Excel or Numbers. Each user only needs to review a subset of the file, so I was hoping to offer an `awk` one-liner that they can use until upstream changes can be made.

The CSV file looks like this:

```
# bot-eod-report.csv
underlying_symbol,id,executed_at,ewma_nbbo_ask,ewma_nbbo_bid
TSLA,TSLA230224C00210000,2023-02-17 20:34:16.639229+00,5.40,5.35
DKNG,DKNG230421C00035000,2023-02-17 20:34:16.616227+00,0.07,0.02
QQQ,QQQ230217C00301000,2023-02-17 20:34:16.616051+00,0.35,0.34
TQQQ,TQQQ230217P00027000,2023-02-17 20:34:16.363909+00,3.15,3.05
PLTR,PLTR230217C00009000,2023-02-17 20:34:16.331521+00,0.18,0.16
QQQJ,QQQJ230217P00027000,2023-02-17 20:34:16.313909+00,3.15,3.05
```

The first column, `underlying_symbol`, contains a string value that the user wants to filter on.

Suppose the user wants to review only rows whose value in column 1 is "QQQ" and keep the first row (which contains column headers), then the output CSV should look like this:

```
underlying_symbol,id,executed_at,ewma_nbbo_ask,ewma_nbbo_bid
QQQ,QQQ230217C00301000,2023-02-17 20:34:16.616051+00,0.35,0.34
```

My first attempt was:

`> awk 'NR==1; NR>1 $1~/QQQ/' bot-eod-report.csv > qqq_only.csv`

But this pattern matches "TQQQ" and "QQQJ", which the user does not want:

```
# qqq_only.csv
underlying_symbol,id,executed_at,ewma_nbbo_ask,ewma_nbbo_bid
QQQ,QQQ230217C00301000,2023-02-17 20:34:16.616051+00,0.35,0.34
TQQQ,TQQQ230217P00027000,2023-02-17 20:34:16.363909+00,3.15,3.05
QQQJ,QQQJ230217P00027000,2023-02-17 20:34:16.313909+00,3.15,3.05
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63061515/3075291

^-- I found this answer, which appeared to be exactly what I needed, and tried:

`> awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} NR==1; NR>1 $1=="QQQ"' bot-eod-report.csv > qqq_only_2.csv`

But this yielded zero rows:

```
# qqq_only_2.csv
underlying_symbol,id,executed_at,ewma_nbbo_ask,ewma_nbbo_bid
```

I am using Windows and figured there might be a single quote / double quote problem, so I tried this variant from that same Stack Overflow answer:

`> awk -v value="QQQ" 'BEGIN{FS=","} NR==1; NR>1 $1==value' bot-eod-report.csv > qqq_only_3.csv`

But again, no matches:

```
# qqq_only_3.csv
underlying_symbol,id,executed_at,ewma_nbbo_ask,ewma_nbbo_bid
```

Removing the file separator section and adjusting the quotes around `value` did not deliver anything either:

(no file separator)

`> awk -v value="QQQ" 'NR==1; NR>1 $1==value' bot-eod-report.csv > qqq_only_4.csv`

```
# qqq_only_4.csv
underlying_symbol,id,executed_at,ewma_nbbo_ask,ewma_nbbo_bid
```

(single quotes instead of double quotes on value)

`> awk -v value='QQQ' 'NR==1; NR>1 $1==value' bot-eod-report.csv > qqq_only_5.csv`

```
# qqq_only_5.csv
underlying_symbol,id,executed_at,ewma_nbbo_ask,ewma_nbbo_bid
```

**For GNU Awk version 5.0.0, what should I use to get exact string matches in the first column?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to print the first row and the row(s) with exact string in first field. If so you can use command like:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 || $1=="QQQ"' bot-eod-report.csv
```

if you want to keep the value in shell variable and use it in `awk` you can try something like:

```
var_shell="QQQ"
awk -F, -v var=$var_shell 'NR==1 || $1=var' bot-eod-report.csv
```

Comment: Thank you this logic works perfectly, now I just need to figure out how to escape this appropriately since the Windows command will not execute this without stalling

Comment: @DanWagner, one possible workaround will be to use MobaXTerm which contains `bash` and `awk` (and run under Windows) and do the work. You can  (in MobaXTerm) walk around local filesystem w/o any problem and exec the command on the right place.